# rails has one relation - grouping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
Class A
 has_many: B
end 

Class B
 belongs_to: A
 has_one: C
end 

Class C
 belongs_to: B
end
```

I want to group the column from the Class C with sum of price column from Class A

```
C.group("c.uniq_code").select("sum(A.price) as total")
```

Please advice:

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
C.select("c.uniq_code, sum(a.price) as total").joins(:b => :a).group('c.uniq_code')
```